Nginx closes connection
I'm runnning a default nginx package on Debian Bookworm. Normally I'm just using the HTTPS connections to that service and everything is fine. Default for HTTP port 80 is a redirect to the HTTPS protocol.
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_tokens off;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}

// vhosts with listen 443 configs omited here, they work

I've an IoT client, that doesnt speak HTTPS. So, I configured it to use HTTP to send sensor data to a hook url on the Nginx server.
I added a VHost for that local domain xyz, that doesn't forward the request to HTTPS but processed it with plain HTTP.
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name xyz;
  server_tokens off;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html/;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}

// vhosts with listen 443 configs omited here, they work

But that request is never processed by the Nginx.
Using curl, I'm getting this response
# curl -v http://localhost/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

(Nginx is listening on all devices, no firewall is active, when I stop the service, the port is closed...).
There is no error log message neither in journald, nor in nginx access or error logs.
Then I tried hardcore telnet to port 80 and got a more strange result:
# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection closed by foreign host.

(to be clear, I've entered GET / HTTP/1.1\n without a second empty line, only one "enter", when I enter something not HTTP conform, like a random string, the server response with ??)
So, right after the first line, Nginx is closing the connection (the HTTP/0.9 response comes from curl itself).
Because I could not set the Host: header in the request, this request never checks any virtual host configuration.
I don't have an idea, what is wrong. The server should at least wait for the Host-header before closing the connection. The /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is not changed.
According to nginx -t the configuration is ok, the server responses normal on curl -v https://localhost/. The SSL configuration etc. is omitted here. It's working.

Your question is very confused. There does not appear to be any IOT client here, the only client we see is curl. Your default server in nginx has no TLS configuration. Using a 301 here is silly. If you mean tha the mystery IOT device is really a server, then you should have shown us what config you added for it.

The IoT device is just a reason, why I need plain http. It calls a hook URL.
And there is a comment, that I stripped the HTTPS communication, because I only have a problem with HTTP calls. Otherwise curl or telnet must return a 301 for default server, but Nginx is immediately closing the http connection without any response.

Because I could not set the Host: header in the request - yes you did, you called localhost.

No, the telnet command didn't set anything. It opens just the socket and sends GET / HTTP/1.1\n.

It doesn't look like nginx on localhost:80. I doubt it could answer with http/0.9 or close connection right after GET line

As I wrote - the HTTP/0.9 comes from curl client itself. It's a default error case, when the socket can be opened, but the server doesnt reply with a correct protocol message (in this case by just closing the connection). The telnet is simulating that on raw level.

When there is no log message at all, there is another option to find the problem. We know, that a plain Nginx works. So, remove ALL virtual host configurations from nginx and start with a simple default setup.
By doing that, I can see, that Nginx is responding as expected.
Then add the earlier virtual host configurations one by one.
The problem was in another virtualhost configuration, that uses the http2 directive in the plain http socket.
server {
  listen 80 http2;
  listen [::]:80 http2;
  server_name abc;
  server_tokens off;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

(older nginx package (1.22.1) on Debian Bookworm doesnt yet support http2 on; configuration)
When this http2 directive is removed, the nginx / curl / telnet / IoT is working as expected.
I could not find a reason, why Nginx is not working properly, when one non-ssl virtual host uses the HTTP/2 directive. But I could reproduce it on several other systems.
The documentation says:

The http2 parameter (1.9.5) configures the port to accept HTTP/2 connections. Normally, for this to work the ssl parameter should be specified as well, but nginx can also be configured to accept HTTP/2 connections without SSL.


Oh I see. Flags on the listen directive are global for the port number, so all your servers that listens to port 80 would use http2. Not an obvious knowledge.

Anyway http2 without ssl is almost meaningless, no real browser supports it.

really? So one listen 443 ssl is enough, that all other listen 443 need SSL setup, even without that directive. Oha. And I was expecting, that http2 directive is backward compatible to http1.

Yeah, http2 on plain port is not backward compatible. It is compatible on https, because browser and server could negotiate protocol using ALPN before http.
